# Создать веб сервер, который будет в зависимости от айпи выводить разные формы

Tags: python, django, веб-сервер, ip-address

Мне дали задачку создать веб сервер, который будет в зависимости от айпи выводить разные формы. Сказали всё делать на питоне, до этого момента я с ним не сталкивался. В общем, создал простенький сайт с помощью django, а вот чтобы хотя бы логировать айпи пользователей, которые заходят на сайт, у меня не получилось. Нашел приложение django-ipware https://github.com/un33k/django-ipware
Там вроде даже и пример есть.

```
 # In a view or a middleware where the `request` object is available
 from ipware import get_client_ip
 client_ip, is_routable = get_client_ip(request)
 if client_ip is None:
    # Unable to get the client's IP address
 else:
     # We got the client's IP address
     if is_routable:
         # The client's IP address is publicly routable on the Internet
     else:
         # The client's IP address is private
 # Order of precedence is (Public, Private, Loopback, None)
```

Но я не понимаю как мне просто отобразить ip. Например есть файл base.html, который я так понимаю отвечает за главную информацию, и мне для теста нужно вывести айпи на главную страницу, как мне это сделать?
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы уже прочитали [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/#first-steps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы получили переменную client_ip, то в шаблоне она выводится {{ client_ip }}
Ее из вашей view функции (где вы используете вышеуказанный код) нужно передать в контекст. В общем вам надо изучить азы django:

1. Как писать view функции
2. Как передаются в шаблон переменные
3. Как выводятся в шаблоне переменные